# HTML 5 canvas and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Here is my code to create a simple canvas,

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('colorPicker').getContext('2d');
gradient1 = canvas1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, colorPicker.width, colorPicker.height);
gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
gradient1.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
canvas1.fillStyle = gradient1;
canvas1.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Any way to change this to apply it to a class rather than an ID as I want it many time on one page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a jQuery class selector, then `.each()` to loop through:

```
// Assumes colorPicker already exists
$('canvas.colorPicker').each(function(){
    var canvas1 = this.getContext('2d');
    gradient1 = canvas1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, colorPicker.width, colorPicker.height);
    gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
    gradient1.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
    canvas1.fillStyle = gradient1;
    canvas1.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
});
```

Comment: There isn't any `canvas.height` in the code you posted, but you would need something like this to set the canvases' height: `$('canvas.colorPicker').each(function(){ this.height = something; });`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".myclass").each(
function() {
  this.getContext('2d');
  gradient1 = canvas1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, colorPicker.width, colorPicker.height);
  gradient1.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
  gradient1.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
  canvas1.fillStyle = gradient1;
  canvas1.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}
);
```